# JS Change string format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string in the following format :

```
One,Two,Three,Four
```

and I want to change its format to `"One","Two","Three","Four"`

I tried the following :

```
var items = ['One,Two,Three,Four'];

var quotedAndCommaSeparated = '"' + items + '"';


document.write(quotedAndCommaSeparated);
```

which adds the double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the string. I don't want to use `replace` because there might be values that have a comma.

Is there a way to split the initial string and return the wanted one?

Comment: Why do you want to wrap them with quotes? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `there might be values that have a comma` how do you determine wether a comma seperates two values or is part of one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want. Split on the commas and then rejoin using the delimiter you are looking for.

```
var quotedAndCommaSeparated = '"'+items[0].split(',').join('","')+'"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
items[0].replace(/^|$/g, '"').replace(/,/g,'","')
```